# Carnivorous Cube, if I steal it, who gets the minions when it dies?

Tags: hearthstone

If I steal a [Carnivorous cube](http://www.hearthpwn.com/cards/73325-carnivorous-cube) with a [Pint Size Potion](http://www.hearthpwn.com/cards/49644-pint-size-potion) and [Cabal Shadow Priest](http://www.hearthpwn.com/cards/147-cabal-shadow-priest) combintaion, what happens when the cube dies? Do I get the two copies or my opponent?

Comment: I'm 90% sure that your opponent gets 2 minions.

Comment: You'll get them. Same thing with moat lurker.

Comment: @FoxMcCloud Moatlurkers interaction is different. it respawns the minion you destroyed.

Comment: @DropDeadSander-EUW And carnivorous cube does it twice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get the copies. When you steal a minion, through any means, it is treated as [belonging to you](https://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Mind_control_effect), so it will work as if you had summoned it:

> Mind control effects or control effects are effects which allow a
>   player to seize control of an enemy minion. **Controlled minions are
>   treated as belonging to the controlling player for all purposes**, can
>   be directed to attack its former allies and owner, and will
>   immediately be transferred to the controlling player's side of the
>   battlefield, to the far right of the board.